# Pandoc - problem with citeproc forcing author's name

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

No matter which CSL I use, Pandoc's citeproc forces the name of the author into the text.

Here's my Markdown:

```markdown
---
bibliography: bib.json
csl: american-school-of-classical-studies-at-athens
...

Computers are complicated @verletComputerExperimentsClassical1967.
```

This should produce

> Computers are complicated<sup>1</sup>

Instead, it produces

> Computers are complicated Verlet<sup>1</sup>

If I use [Harvard Cite Them Right](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=id%3Aharvard-cite-them-right&format=author-date&dependent=0) it should produce

> Computers are complicated (Verlet, 1967).

Instead, I get

> Computers are complicated Verlet (1967).

How do I get citeproc to follow the specified CSL?

I'm running `pandoc --citeproc test.md -o test.html` to generate the output.

Version is  pandoc 2.19.2, citeproc 0.8.0.1.

### Update

It works as expected if the citation in Markdown is wrapped with `[` and `]`

`Computers are complicated [@verletComputerExperimentsClassical1967].`

Is that meant to happen, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be by design, citations without square brackets are called "*in-text citations*" in Quarto docs and "*author-in-text citations*" in Pandoc docs:

> ###### Citation Syntax
>
> Quarto uses the standard Pandoc markdown
> representation for citations (e.g. [@citation]) — citations go inside
> square brackets and are separated by semicolons.
> /../
> You can also write in-text citations, as follows:
> MD: `@knuth1984 says blah.` ; Output: *Knuth (1984) says blah.*
>
> https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/footnotes-and-citations.html

---

> ##### Extension: citations
>
> To cite a bibliographic item with an identifier foo, use the syntax @foo.
> Normal citations should be
> included in square brackets, with semicolons separating distinct items
> /../
> You can also write an author-in-text citation, by omitting the square brackets
>
> https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations